# Escaping ../ in browser pathname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, pathname

I'm currently working on some project in react and search query is represented as ***/search/:query***. 

 It works fine when query is ***"something"***, but I search for ***"something/../../else"*** it change url to ***"/else"***.

 Route doesn't change but url does.

 I use react-router-dom and pathname is updated on search input submit.

```
this.props.history.push('/search/' + searchValue);
```

How can I escape searchValue so it doesn't mess up url after submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to escape the search value like this : encodeURIComponent()
doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: <Route path="/search/*" component={Search} /> This is in main App.js file inside <Router>. It doesn't mess up routes and components. It just mess up url pathname in browser